# Update a json inside a json in react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a json of this kind:

```
person{
   skin:'exampleSkin',
   legs:{
      skin:'exampleSkinLegs',
      stuff:[
        {
          name:'stuffName'
        }
      ],
      legStuff:'legStuffExample'
   }
   eyes:'eyes'
}
```

This var is on my state.

What I want to do is on my frontend method give the user the option to input the fields and create this person and add it to a list,but I cannot map this to my handleChange method.

Note that this json is just an example, its not my real one but the format is the same.

Comment: object not "a json"

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `bind()` the function to the constructor for using `this` or you can simply convert it to an arrow function.

```
class Example extends Component {
  state = { skin:'exampleSkin' }
  handleOnChange = () => {
    this.setState({skin: 'anotherExampleSkin' })
  }
  render() {
    return ( //code that uses this.handleOnChange );
  }
}

export default Example;
```